# Including both "careful" and "dangerous" versions of a function in a library/module

Tags: libraries, modularization

I'm writing some code that I've decoupled off into a module of its own, and even though I'm most likely the only person who will use it, I'm trying to think as if I might not be. The functions in this module perform operations on objects in an array that's passed in, and right now, I'm doing a bunch of safety checks to avoid exceptions caused by getting bad data – specifically, accounting for the possibility of an undefined/null value for that array, or one of the objects in the array, or one of the properties on one of the objects. In other words, quite a lot of checking. However, in the application where this module is used, I've already checked for all of these things before sending the data to be processed by this module – because null values in this data will cause problems elsewhere, as well.

Now that everything is working smoothly, I'm tempted to remove some of the safety checks in my module for the sake of efficiency, since I'm duplicating work. However, if this module *were* to be used by someone else, I would think that it'd be better to make it as bulletproof as possible – so if bad data is passed in from their end, my module will be able to handle it without being responsible for any crashes. But then I thought that a hypothetical person using my module might be in the same position I'm in – confident the data they're passing in is good, because they've already checked it.

To me, the obvious solution is to have two versions of certain key functions in the module: a 'careful' version if you don't trust the data, and a 'dangerous' version if you do trust it, and just want to maximise performance. Is this something that's done? Assuming good documentation, would it be a good idea? And if it *were* a good idea, would it be better to differentiate between the two on a per-function basis, e.g. `processSafely(data)` and `liveDangerously(data)`) – or via seperate namespaces within the module – `myModule.safe.process(data)` and `myModule.reckless.process(data)`?

EDIT: The answers so far have been valuable, but I thought I should add (without veering too far into Stack Overflow territory) that the specific module I'm talking about is designed to accept a (potentially large) array of blog articles as objects (as they would come from a parser of a fairly standard format), extract tags out of said articles and count them, and return an array containing each individual tag with its count. In other words, as with all tasks involving parsing of files/objects *supposedly* conforming to a given format, there's sort of a lot that can go wrong, but I (or the user) will probably have to account for that elsewhere anyway (e.g. before rendering the articles to a view or whatever). Also, all of the checks I'm talking about are O(n) – not just one or two preliminary if statements or type coercions.

Comment: Did you profile it and did the profiling show a significant performance gain due to the omitted checks?

Comment: No, I haven't. I haven't actually removed any checks yet, this was me procrastinating about taking that leap. Would that be the deciding factor? Actually, the problem is that with the dataset I have now, any improvements would be negligible. To meaningfully do any kind of profiling/stress testing I'd need to increase the amount of data I was processing by at least an order of magnitude, so I'd also need to programmatically create more dummy data.

Comment: Sounds like you need to wait until you have an actual performance problem.  I know that doesn't sound proactive, but unless and until you have an actual performance problem, those checks are always going to be more valuable than the miniscule performance improvements you *might* get by removing them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It may be useful to keep checks in place unless or until a performance problem is demonstrated.  If redundant checks *might* cause performance problems in future, however, having callers indicate from the get-go whether validation is required or has already been performed will facilitate the elimination of redundant checks *should that become necessary*.  Trying to patch callers after-the-fact to indicate when checks should be omitted would seem more expensive and trouble-prone than to include such information from the start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, it is really valuable to have a function check all its preconditions even when you “know” everything will be all right. Everything that we let the computer do for us, we can't mess up and introduce accidental mistakes. There are some techniques how this can be implemented efficiently (e.g. as assertions that can be turned off for production builds), but I feel those tend to trade a substantial amount of safety for often little gain.

Instead, we can try to build water-tight abstractions where a constraint is checked once at runtime, and the type system of the language proves the constraint will never be invalidated.

As an example, I might have a function that operates on email addresses: `sendEmail(String to, String subject, String plainTextMessage)`. This function will now have to check that the `String to` is a legal email address. This check will be repeated unnecessarily when you send multiple emails to the same address. Instead, we can define a `class EmailAddress` that checks in the constructor `EmailAddress(String maybeAddress)` whether the string is a legal address. If not, it throws. If so, the object is initialized with that address. This check is done once at construction, afterwards you can use it without additional checks.

However, we will need external access to the underlying string. It is important that this access is read-only. If the underlying type is mutable or if your language does not support const references, it can make sense to proxy the safe methods to the object rather than exposing it. After doing this, we might end up with `sendEmail(EmailAddress to, EmailSubject subject, String body)`.

This technique is especially applicable in statically typed languages with good encapsulation mechanisms where defining a new type is easy to do. I routinely use this technique in C++ and occasionally in Java. In dynamic languages, it is less useful since there are no static type checks. However, the consuming function now only has to do a runtime type check, which is usually less expensive than the full precondition check.

Comment: I guess my case would be something more like if I had written a module that includes a function like sendEmails(array_of_Email_objects) – right now, it contains an awful lot of code along the lines of `for email in array_of_Email_objects {for addresses in email.recipients { [...]` and so forth – more than one O(n) operation, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

When possible, the best way to handle this is to encode your preconditions in the type system. Then ensure that the only way to have an instance of your precondition-asserting type is via a function which forces the caller to handle failure, such as one returning an `Option`/`Optional`/`Maybe` type.

The benefit to this is that code which violates your method's preconditions cannot compile.

For example, in scala,

```
def toPosInt(n: Int): Option[Int] = if (n > 0) Some(n) else None
// Find the square root of a positive number
def sqrt(n: PosInt): Float = ???
```

It's not possible to call this sqrt with a negative number because you can't get a PosInt for a negative number. Java 8 has a similar `Optional` type, and so on.

Comment: Right, so in other words, I should be thinking more in terms of throwing an exception or returning an error code at the first sign of trouble than in terms of trying to soldier on regardless and produce a 'best effort' result?

Comment: @Toadfish This approach is a little more than that, there's no exceptions or error returns, you just can't compile the code calling it the wrong way because an `Option[Int]` is not an `Int`.

Comment: Right, I think I follow. I'll keep your advice in mind when I have the privilege of working in a language that actually *has* types again, hah. I'm currently on planet JS where you have to do all that kind of checking yourself if you don't want a crash, or the even worse case where it *seems* to work until something really bizarre starts happening...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities:

1) Soldier on, parse every thing you can and never complain.  Ignore all those 404s, bad HTML, and nulls.  This is a terrible option.  Lots of work for you, and the client has no idea that the results may not be what they think they should be.  If, for example, blogs plugging Bernie have more errors than blogs praising Hillary, your results will be biased.

A great quote from a strong critique of PHP on why you shouldn't soldier on" "When faced with either doing something nonsensical or aborting with an error, it will do something nonsensical"

2) Throw a useful exception on the first bad input.  Easier to code, more useful to the client.  But still annoying - hard for them to fix one at a time.

3) Soldier on, but ignore "bad blogs".  However, keep a List of all the bad blogs (and ideally a description, e.g. " link has a 404") and return that to the client.  They get feedback that there were errors and can decide if their results are "good enough".  Also something you can unit test by including some known bad inputs.